# Does putting request.getQueryString in response.sendRedirect make you vulnerable to HTTP Response Splitting?

Tags: java, security, http, servlets

I made this minimal JSP:

```
<%
    response.sendRedirect(request.getQueryString());
%>
```

Obviously it's not very useful, but it is enough to trigger a FindBugs warning I am also getting on my real JSP:

> This code directly writes an HTTP parameter to an HTTP header, which
>   allows for a HTTP response splitting vulnerability

However, I'm pretty sure FindBugs is wrong here.  Per [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString()) `getQueryString` does not decode the query string, and I don't believe the encoded query string can contain a CRLF because it has to be in the request line.  So as far as I can tell, there's no way a CRLF could get in there.

This toy page is going to have a problem if the query string is null, and the string will be interpreted as relative or not which is probably not great, but is there an HTTP response splitting vulnerability here?

If there is, how could we prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is YES. But there are more security issues than only response splitting (aka header or CRLF injection). There is also an "unvalidated redirect" issue. An attacker can redirect your customer through your site to some other dangerous site (phishing, exploiting, etc).

The solution is to create a whitelist and check if the current target is inside the whitelist. This prevents both issues. Encoding the value would just be the solution to the response splitting issue but doesn't work against the redirect issue.

Comment: How would the response splitting occur?

Comment: You can basically put %0D%0A as newline to add new headers, but it depens on other protections from your jre, app server, aso.

Comment: That doesn't work.  If you put `%0D%0A` in the query string you get `%0D%0A` in the Location, because as documented `getQueryString` doesn't decode the query string, and `sendRedirect` of course doesn't decode it either.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard: but the browser decodes it before sending it along, effectively sending control characters, which are included as such in `getQueryString` and `sendRedirect`

Comment: response.sendRedirect("/example.do?" + request.getQueryString());  Will this cause open redirect issue ? As i am not directly passing  request.getQueryString() to response.sendRedirect.